# Scheduler on Debian

Tags: debian, scheduled-tasks, web2py

Upstart does not exist in the debian on beaglebone and i do not want to mess with that. There is a script developed in https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/scripts/setup-scheduler-centos.sh which uses chkconfig to add the service to the start up. chkconfig also does not exist in the debian.
I tried to modify the script and use update-rc.d, however all the attempts failed.
What ultimately I want to do is to run periodic tasks and any suggestion is welcome and appreciated. I know about Celery but I found Massimo's argument about scheduler convincing and wanted to use it. By the way, what are the main drawbacks of web2py cron? Should I try to use that?

Comment: I think your question would be more appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com/) since you do not have any coding problem (at least you didn't show code that fails). Also *drawbacks of web2py cron* should be a separate question (if at all, since answers to that are probably opinion based).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run simple periodic background tasks I suggest using web2py's "Homemade task queues." Using the following terminal command will give any python script access to your application's Models, while running in the background (you can use cron to schedule this command to run on startup):

```
nohup python web2py.py -S myapp -M -R applications/myapp/private/myscript.py
```

Your custom script (usually kept in the /private folder of your application) may look something like this:

```
## in file /myapp/private/mail_queue.py
import time
while True:
    rows = db(db.queue.status=='pending').select()
    for row in rows:
        if mail.send(to=row.email,
            subject=row.subject,
            message=row.message):
            row.update_record(status='sent')
        else:
            row.update_record(status='failed')
        db.commit()
    time.sleep(60) # check every minute
```

This is sample a script from the web2py docs that checks for pending messages (every 60 seconds) in the db and sends out an email. Note, your script should be a periodic while loop, and unlike Controllers, you must use db.commit() after making changes to the db.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `apt-get install gnome-schedule`